# Custom hook not using useState() properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make one of those custom useKeyPress hooks, and I want my keydown handler to fire on every individual button press, i.e. holding down a key won't trigger it a million times. I'm trying to do this by having a flag that indicates whether to call the handler, `callHandler` - it should only be set to true when the target key is released/the component just mounted. Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

```
const useKeyPress = (target)=>{
   const [callHandler, setCallHandler] = useState(true);

   const keyDown = (e) =>{
      if(e.key === target && callHandler){
         setCallHandler(false); //This line never seems to work properly???
         console.log(callHandler, setCallHandler);

         //call the keyDown handler
      }
   }

   const keyUp = (e)=>{
      if(e.key === target)
         setCallHandler(true);
   }

   useEffect(()=>{
      document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
      document.addEventListener('keyup' keyUp);

      return ()=>{
         document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
         document.removeEventListener('keyup', keyUp);
      }
   },[]);
}

useKeyPress('a');
```

My issue is that callHandler is never set to false. That console log immediately after setCallHandler just spams the debug screen with (true, ...) when I hold down the 'a' key, meaning that despite the code block running callHandler is somehow always false. Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: const useKeyPress = (target) => {..

Comment: @andriishupta My bad, that was a typo when I was writing up this post. My actual code doesn't have that mistake.

Comment: noticed later, sorry) looking into further

Comment: keydown and keyup are original events, not camelCased

Comment: with only this change - some stuff is logged into console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if i get it right , anyway i made this code hope helps u a bit.

**EDIT**

Change it to custom hook example, maybe useful for someone in future.

```js
const useKeyEvent = (target) =>{
  const [keyTarget,setKeyTarget] = React.useState(target);
  const [playedKey,setPlayedKey] = React.useState(null);
  const [keyDone,setKeyDone] = React.useState(false);
  
  const keyUp = (e) => {
      setPlayedKey(null);
      setKeyDone(false)
  };
  const keyDown = (e) => {
        const key = e.key;
        if (key !== playedKey) {
            if(key === keyTarget){
              setKeyDone(true);
            }
          setPlayedKey(key);
        }
 };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
    };
  }, [keyUp, keyDown,keyDone]);
  
  return [playedKey,keyTarget,setKeyTarget,keyDone];
}

const App = () => {
  const [playedKey,keyTarget,setKeyTarget,keyDone] = useKeyEvent("a");
  return (
  <div>
    <h3 style={{color:keyDone?"green":"black"}}>Press {keyTarget} key ! Key : {playedKey}</h3>
    <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>setKeyTarget(e.currentTarget.value)} maxLength="1" value={keyTarget}/>
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does! I just changed my old code to use playedKey as a flag (instead of a bool) and it worked. Still not sure why though...

Comment: happy to help you :)