# Unable to fetch data from api in component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rest

I am working on this project in React JS where I fetch data from this [API URL](http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/images/) for my frontend development.

I have made my custom hooks to fetch the data into several files following [this medium article](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/implementing-a-rest-api-with-react-hooks-using-patterns-2ea1476e2a05) as follows:

*useApiResult.js*

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useApiResult = (request) => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(request)
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          setResults(await response.json());
          setError(null);
        } else {
          setError(await response.text())
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
      });
  }, [request]);

  return [results, error];
};
```

*useImages.js*

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useApiResult } from "./useApiResult";

const BASE_URL = "http://api.vidyarajkumari.com";
const createUrl = (base, path) => `${base}${path}`;

const getImages = () => [
  createUrl(BASE_URL, "/images/"),
  {
      method: "GET",
  }
];

export const useImages = () => {
  const request = useMemo(() => getImages(), []);
  return useApiResult(request);
}
```

React component: *Images.js*

```
import React from "react";
import { useImages } from "../../hooks/useImages";

export default function Images() {
  const [images, error] = useImages();
  //console.log(images);
  //console.log(error);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="row">
        {
          images.map((item, index) => {
            <div key={index} className="col-md-4 animate-box">
            ...
            // Rest of code goes here
          }
        }
      </>
    </>
  )
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to get the data in the **Images.js** component from the **useImages** hook. The `console.log` values of images return **null**. This has been bugging me for a while now and I would greatly appreciate a solution to this. What am I doing wrong here and how can I work around this?

P.S. The API Url is live; so feel free to reference it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I Have a better way to do this using `useReducer` and custom hook, check this:

By the way, I think your API URL has some problems! (I added input for fetching another URL for test)

```js
const IMAGE_URL = "http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/images/";

const initialState = { loading: true };

function fetchReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "fetch":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: undefined,
        loading: true,
      };

    case "data":
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data,
        loading: false,
      };

    case "error":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: "Error fetching data. Try again",
        loading: false,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function useFetch(url) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(fetchReducer, initialState);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "fetch" });

    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => dispatch({ type: "data", data }))
      .catch((e) => {
        console.warn(e.message);
        dispatch({ type: "error" });
      });
  }, [url]);

  return {
    loading: state.loading,
    data: state.data,
    error: state.error,
  };
}

function FetchComponent({url}) {
  const { loading, data, error } = useFetch(url);
  console.log(data);
  if (loading) {
    return <p>Fetching {url}...</p>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>{error}</p>
  }
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
}

const App = () => {
  const [url, setUlr] = React.useState(IMAGE_URL)
  const inputEl = React.useRef(null);
  const changeUrl = () => setUlr(inputEl.current.value)
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input defaultValue="https://icanhazdadjoke.com/" ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={changeUrl}>Fetch</button>
      {url && <FetchComponent url={url}/>}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is an approach that looks cleaner. Can you elaborate on what problems you are referring to regarding the API url?

Comment: I think you are using hooks `useImages()` in the wrong way, check my hook you'll find that.

Comment: also, check my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65224984/12608714 you can understand it better.

Comment: The API was written by a friend so unfortunately, I have no control over that. Is there a way you could work around with it using your hooks to make it work if that is not asking for much?

Comment: Do you mean I change your backend? or you want your example to works?

Comment: No. I was asking  if you could explore the URL and see if it can be made to return the data instead of the error from within the useFetch hook of yours. Because I can't seem to but I'm trying.

Comment: I made an input inside my example you can try another URL and see the result!

Comment: I have. Nevertheless, thanks for the tips. I will try to find a way around it.

Comment: I found the correct URL try this inside input: http://api.vidyarajkumari.com/images/?format=json

Comment: Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Give results and error also, in the dependency array, So that component get render when result is updated.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useApiResult = (request) => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(request)
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          setResults(await response.json());
          setError(null);
        } else {
          setError(await response.text())
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err.message);
      });
  }, [request, results, error]);

  return [results, error];
};
```

Comment: Noted. But I think this is an improvement rather than a solution to my problem. But appreciate the suggestion.